# Trying to create an array of Struct and load data from file

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have this struct i created called User which stores all kind of data,
now i'm trying to create an array of it (User*) and get data from a file,
this is what i do in the start of my main program:

```
int amount = 0;
User* users = NULL;

// read from file functions
loadUsers(&users,&amount);
```

And the function (the amount of users is the first line of my txt file):

```
void loadUsers(User** users,int* amount2){
    int amount, i = 0, j;
    char temp[STRING_SIZE], temp2[STRING_SIZE];
    FILE* f;

    f = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (!f){
        return;
    }

    if (fileEmpty(f)){
        return;
    }

    fscanf(f, "%d", &amount);
    *amount2 = amount;

    *users = malloc(sizeof(User)*amount);
    /**users = (User*)malloc(sizeof(User)*amount);*/

    while (!feof(f)){
        fscanf(f, "%s", temp);
        users[i]->ID = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp) + 1));
        strcpy(users[i]->ID, temp);
        fscanf(f, "%s", temp);
        users[i]->f_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp) + 1));
        strcpy(users[i]->f_name, temp);
        fscanf(f, "%s", temp);
        users[i]->l_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp) + 1));
        strcpy(users[i]->l_name, temp);

        i++;
    }
```

For some reason i get an error and while debugging i see the allocation is wrong since i only have `users[0]` and not `users[1]`, like an array of users should have, even when the amount is higher than 1.

My target is to have an array, which each cell of it is a User.

What could be the reason?

Edit:
User struct:

```
struct User{
    char* ID;
    char* f_name;
    char* l_name;
    int age;
    char gender;
    char* username;
    char* password;
    char* description;
    char** hobbies;
}typedef User;
```

Comment: What do you mean by _i only have `users[0]`_?

Comment: How does input.txt look like?

Comment: show the `User` struct

Comment: why don't you try this `char id[100]; f_name[100]; l_name[100]; while ((i < amount) && (fscanf(f, "%99s%99s%99s", id, f_name, l_name) == 3)) { /* copy the strings to users[i] here */ };`.

Comment: @iharob imagine i had an array of int, i would have arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] etc..

Comment: I mean how do you know you don't?

Comment: @iharob while debugging it doesn't have an adress or content after allocating, and when i try to add data to something which is not 'users[0]' i get an error.

Comment: What error? Your problem does not make any sense, and your program hould be working, what debugger are you using what compiler and OS?

Comment: If you are only getting a single User record (which is what I think you mean by 'i only have users[0]', then check your fscanf of `amount` . Trying printing the value of `amount` after you read it to see what value you get.

Comment: @argamanza did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be invoking undefined behavior because you don't check for `i < amount` in the while loop, you also don't check for `fscanf()` to see if it did succesfully read the data, if it fails, tha contents of the `temp` array would be uninitialized and trying to copy them to the `malloc`ed poitners is Undefined Behavior too.

So your problem is basically that your program is blindly assuming that everything is working as expected and potentially invoking Undefined Behavior, that mistake is very commong among new programmers.

You are allocating space for `amount` structs of `User` and yet you try to initialize `amount` pointers of `User` in the for loop, you should dereference the double pointer for it to work properly.

This is your own code with some checks that will prevent undefined behavior

```
void loadUsers(User** userlist, int* amount2)
{
    int  amount, i = 0;
    char id[100];
    char fname[100];
    char lname[100];
    FILE *file;
    User *users;

    file = fopen("input.txt", "r");

    if (!file) {
        return;
    }

    if (fileEmpty(file)) {
        fclose(file);
        return;
    }
    if (fscanf(file, "%d", &amount) != 1)
    {
        fclose(file);
        return;
    }

    *amount2  = amount;
    *userlist = malloc(sizeof(User) * amount);
    if (*userlist == NULL)
        return; /* malloc can fail, check that */

    /* point to the destination pointer to prevent the need of (*users)[i] */
    users = *userlist;
    /* if fscanf() returns 3 it means that all the arguments where read */
    while ((i < amount) && (fscanf(file, "%99s%99s%99s", id, fname, lname) == 3)) {
        size_t length;

        length      = strlen(id);
        users[i].ID = malloc(length + 1); /* sizeof(char) == 1 */
        if (users[i].ID != NULL)
            strcpy(users[i].ID, id);

        length          = strlen(fname);
        users[i].f_name = malloc(length + 1); /* sizeof(char) == 1 */
        if (users[i].f_name != NULL)
            strcpy(users[i].f_name, fname);

        length          = strlen(lname);
        users[i].l_name = malloc(length + 1); /* sizeof(char) == 1 */
        if (users[i].l_name != NULL)
            strcpy(users[i].l_name, lname);

        i++;
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: I see you also correct "*users = malloc(sizeof(User)*amount);" to be "users = malloc(sizeof(User)*amount);" (implicitly).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie iharob correctly wrote `*userlist = malloc(sizeof(User) * amount);` unlike your answer. Take a closer look. He then went `users = *userlist;` so that the assignments are more straight forward.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie what do you mean? I don't understand, Wheather Vane's answer is not wrong.

Comment: @iharob: Yes, Whether Vane's answer is correct, but in the posted code he also fixed another error, namely that you derferenced Users in your original code when assigning the malloc result.

Comment: @iharob: I didn't see Users was passed aas a double pointer. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error over the double pointer. Instead of this:

```
users[i]->ID = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(temp) + 1));
strcpy(users[i]->ID, temp);
```

Try this:

```
(*users)[i].ID = malloc(strlen(temp) + 1);
strcpy ((*users)[i].ID, temp);
```

And so on for the other fields.

Comment: The expressions are equivalent. In "users[i]", the compiler knows that 'users' is a pointer. It takes the value stored in users and adds i * sizeof(struct User) to it. We now have a pointer to a struct User, which you can dereference with the -> operator. In "(*users)[i]" the compiler dereferences users, which yields a struct User, and add i * sizeof(struct User) to that. We now have an expression of type struct User and can use the dot-operator to access the members. Hence the two are equivalent.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie you are wrong. Using a single-indirection pointer gives the wrong results as OP found. I compiled and ran a simple program testing both methods, and using `users[i]->ID` works only for the first element, as OP found. Did you down vote me? Have you tested you own answer?

Comment: You are righ; I didn't see Users was passed as a double pointer. So indeed there must be a double indirection.